# Subset of a sql table - number of records and sum of a field

Tags: java, sql, select

I wish to select a subset of a table

I then want to count the number of records in this subset

And finally get the sum of one particular field

My code is as follows:-

```
// get the subset of records in the XXXXXX table
ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 FROM XXXXXXX " 
    + "WHERE Field1 = ? AND Field2 = ? AND Field3 = ? "
    + "GROUP BY Field1, Field2, Field3");
ps.setString(1, variable1);
ps.setString(2, variable2);
ps.setString(3, variable3);
rs = ps.executeQuery(); 

int recordCount1 = 0;
while (rs.next()) {
recordCount1 = recordCount1 + rs.getInt(1);
}

rs.close();
ps.close(); 

myConsole.getOut().println("Number of records in Subset1 of table
   XXXXXXX: " + recordCount1);

// now split the subset into those records where P/L > 0  
and those records where P/L <0 
// positive P/L
ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 "
    + "SUM(PL) AS Total_Profit FROM XXXXXX "
    + "WHERE Field1 = ? AND Field2 = ? AND Field3 = ? "
    + "AND PL >= 0 "
    + "GROUP BY Field1, Field2, Field3");
ps.setString(1, variable1);
ps.setString(2, variable2);
ps.setString(3, variable3);
rs = ps.executeQuery(); 

int recordCount2a = 0;
while (rs.next()) {
recordCount2a = recordCount2a + rs.getInt(1);
}

myConsole.getOut().println("Number of records in Subset of table
XXXXXX where P/L >= 0: " + recordCount2a);
```

---

I am getting a zero count for the number of records in the subset

Are there areas of the code which are incorrect ?

Comment: I think you should edit your question to make clear exactly what you are trying to query.  Also please add a tag for the language you are using (Java?).

Answer (score 0):

First query. -> Display count FIELD1

```
SELECT FIELD1, COUNT(FIELD1) FROM XXXXX
WHERE FIELD1= ? AND FIELD2=? AND FIELD3=?
GROUP BY FIELD1
```

Second query -> Display count of FIELD1 and its PL SUM

```
SELECT FIELD1, COUNT(FIELD1), SUM(PL) AS Total_Profit FROM XXXXX
WHERE FIELD1= ? AND FIELD2=? AND FIELD3=? AND PL > 0
GROUP BY FIELD1
```